# After logging to system HDD LED doesn't stop shine

Tags: 13.04, wine, hard-drive

I noticed the problem first time when the system (13.04) has crashed after trying to run WoW:Cataclysm by the **wine**. When logging to Ubuntu, the HDD diode begins to shine and won't stop, and system is going terribly slow.

I have found that terminating some process like **tracker-store** solves the problem, but this is a bad solution. I started a little poke in the system and have found that some data stores to **/home/username/.xsession-errors** when the **tracker-store** is active, and there are some data like this:

> (tracker-miner-fs:22819): Tracker-WARNING **: Could not open directory "some_directory"
>
> ** (zeitgeist-datahub:23085): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:231: Unable to get name "org.gnome.zeitgeist.datahub" on the bus!

I found solution to stop logging into this file, but this did not solve this problem, after that the HDD still works like being formatted or scanned for viruses. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I have just deleted some folders in home directory like **.local** and **.cache**